# get aria-valuenow property from a div

Tags: javascript

I am using rateit plugin in my webpage, http://rateit.codeplex.com/ and examples here: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm

I set the code for getting the 5 stars div and now I want to get the value for sending to my server. Checking the code, the value is in the div in a property called: aria-valuenow but I don't know how to get the value from that. How can I access to this property?

This is the code I have to create div:

```
<input  type="hidden" value="4" step="1" id="backing4">
<div class="rateit"onclick="rate(this)"  data-rateit-backingfld="#backing4" data-rateit-resetable="false"  data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="5">
</div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
document.getElementById("backing4").aria-valuenow
```

And it says that this property doesn't exists.

Comment: add somecode that you tried.

Comment: I added some code. I don't know if this is what you want

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the aria-valuenow attribute to get the value of your rateit component, you should use the following code:

Use:

```
$('#backing4').val();
```

or

```
$('.rateit').rateit('value');
```

Comment: How does this access `aria-valuenow` property?

Comment: You shouldn't use the aria-valuenow property. Rather use the above mentioned code to get the value. (FYI: I'm the creator of the plugin, so to get downvoted was kind of funny :) )

Comment: And 1) the aria-valuenow does not exist on the backingfield, but on the rateit div. 2) to get a value like that it should be something like document.getElementById('XXX').getAttribute('aria-valuenow')

Comment: I tried using `getAttribute('aria-valuenow')` and didn't work, and looks like the OP was trying to do the same, and your answer doesn't seem like solving it.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/sm3UP/  for a working sample. Besides that the user wants to know how to get the value of the rateit component. He thinks he has to use the aria-valuenow attribute, yet the correct way is not the aria attribute, but the code in my answer. The discussion about the attribute is purely academic, and is not the answer to the core of the question.

Comment: Ok, I understood now, my mystake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing aria-valuenow property from a div is as simple as writing

```
document.getElementById("example").ariaValueNow
```

and if you need to set or change it then,

```
document.getElementById("example").ariaValueNow = "value"
```